# Read text file to 2D array in specially way

Tags: c++, arrays, ifstream

I need to read a special file, and the first line is two number the number of rows and number of column and the next is some text.
Like:

```
2 2
ab
cd
```

What I need to do make a 2-d array and put the text in to array, like `array[2][2]`, and all text must be in the array. This is what I do now.

```
if stream file;
file.open("name.in")
char array[][]
```

Comment: I can see at least three reasons why that code will not do what you want it to do.

Comment: i don't know who to get these two numbers in file then put rest of text in ad array.

Answer (score 0):

When you could use std::string this is a easy solution. This is the code for reading the first line of your file.

```
fstream file;
file.open("name.in", ios::in|ios::out);
string line;
getline(file,line);
char help= line.at(0);
```

With char help you could extract the number with the function std::stoi.

For reading the hole file until the end you could these code lines

```
while (getline(file, line)  ) {
    // Do your Stuff with the text
}
```

Comment: is the 2nd function means, I can  directly type like this : for (i=0;i <= num; i++).....file>>array[10][10] and this array don't contain the first line.

Comment: you get the line of text in the variable <<line>> it's stopping when getline reached end of file.